# sql get column from the 'EXISTS' statemenent

Tags: mysql, sql, select, exists

i have the following sql query

```
SELECT Store.*
FROM Store
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT Contest.StoreID .....) 
OR EXISTS (
    SELECT Discount.StoreID .....)
```

my problem is that i want to include to the results some columns from the Contest and the Discount arrays. If I join them on the `FROM` it works but is there a way to get the values from the `EXISTS` ? something like this

```
SELECT Store.*, t1.something, t2.somethingElse
FROM Store
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT Contest.StoreID .....) t1 
OR EXISTS (
    SELECT Discount.StoreID .....) t2
```

Comment: No, this is not possible. You have to `JOIN` the tables in order to have access to their fields.

Comment: Absolutely not. There is no data exchanged back to the query through the where clause. And tables are not arrays :)

Answer (score 2):

**No**, its not possible to select from the `WHERE` clause, think about it, this clause if for filtering.

There are two ways for selecting data from different tables together, a `sub query` or with a `join`.

Here is a `JOIN` example :

```
SELECT s.*, t1.something, t2.somethingElse
FROM Store s
LEFT OUTER JOIN Contest t1 ON(...)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Discount t2 ON(...)
WHERE t1.<column> is not null OR t2.<column> is not null
```

This will do the same as your query with the `EXISTS()` , and will probably have similar performance.

Can also be done we a correlated sub query :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT s.*,
           (SELECT t1.something FROM contest t1 WHERE t1.<col> = s.<col>) as col1,                       
           (SELECT t1.something FROM contest t1 WHERE t1.<col> = s.<col>) as col2, 
    FROM Store s) t
WHERE t.col1 is not null or t.col2 is not null
```

Comment: JOINs are probably the easiest way for less experienced users.

Comment: I know, but if he is familiar with joins already, he should expand his knowledge @Wh1T3h4Ck5